How to enable captions by default in Vimeo showcase embed
I have a Vimeo playlist, called a showcase, that I embed on a website. Each video has captions and I want to enable them by default on every video. For a single video, the code is (documentation):
https://player.vimeo.com/video/[video_id]?texttrack=fr

For showcases, I tried this code:
https://vimeo.com/showcase/[showcase_id]/embed?texttrack=fr

but the captions do not show by default. They show if I click on the "CC" button and then on "French".
How can I enable captions by default on all videos in a showcase?

According to the Vimeo Support Team, this is impossible at the moment (April 2024):

According to the development team, this is expected behavior, and that
showcases do no not support the texttrack query param, just the
videos.
I will open a feedback request to our product team to
consider adding this behavior in the future if possible.

One solution is to have an iframe showing the first video, with captions enabled by default, and move to the next video in the showcase with JavaScript. I wrote code for this case, if anyone wants it, add a comment and I'll format it to add to the answer.

If you add &amp;texttrack=en-x-autogen in your source url in the embed, that will make subtitles play by default (english only).
